# What's the difference between "+" and "\+"?

Tags: javascript

As I know `+` is a special character, so when I need to use it , should I use `"+"` or `"\+"`?

However I did this comparison which indicates they are just the same thing.

```
console.log("Comare Result  :"   +   ("\+" == "+"));   //return true
```

Is backslash needed here?

Comment: Special with respect to what? Do you mean inside an URL?

Comment: Are you actually referring to + in a regular expression?

Comment: The actual special character in your strings `"+"` and `"\+"` is the backslash. + is a + is a +, at least: inside a string. Regex's and expressions are something else entirely

Answer (score 0):

A backslash in a string indicates that the next character is a special character (such as \n is a new line). If it's not a special character, it'll just interpret it as the character itself. \+ doesn't mean anything, so it'll just be interpreted as a +

Answer (score 0):

Special characters are not an absolute, it always depends on the context. In a JavaScript string, `+` is not special at all. *(It is special in a URL, a regular expression or a mathematical formula.)*

As about, `\+`, it's an unknown [escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Escaping_characters), thus the slash just gets removed:

> For characters not listed [...], a preceding backslash is ignored, but this usage is deprecated and should be avoided.